# Robustness to Additive Uncertainty Proof using small gain theorem

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, robust-control

I am trying to use the small-gain theorem to prove the robust stability condition for additive uncertainty. I have been stuck on it for a while now.

**Question:** How can I use the small-gain theorem to prove the following condition. For a noice model $ \tilde G(s) = G(s) + \Delta(s) W(s) $, the condition for robust stability is $||W(s)C(s)S(s)||_{\infty} < 1$, where:

- $C(s)$ is the controller transfer function
- $S(s)$ is the sensitivity transfer function $S(s) = \frac{1}{1 + G(s)C(s)} $
- $W(s)$ is a weighting transfer function in the uncertainty

Does anyone have a link to a complete proof using this method? I find notes on the internet that simply leave it as an exercise for the reader, but I am getting stuck along the way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Over my head, but some papers (e.g. on "disk margin") point to the reference text: [A Course In Robust Control Theory (Dullerud & Paganini 2000)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3290-0) for these things. (it is more mathematical than most engineers, including myself, are used to). If you search you might find the whole thing online

Comment: Thanks @PeteW! I'll take a look at that.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a block diagram to go along with the equations?